# Making mapped with category's Functor

Tags: haskell, functor, haskell-lens, category-theory, category-abstractions

I love [`mapped`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.1/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:mapped) from the lens package.

```
mapped :: Prelude.Functor f => Setter (f a) (f b) a b
```

However I have recently started to use [`Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-0.2.5.0/docs/Control-Categorical-Functor.html) from the category package (from here out I will refer to category's `Functor` just as `Functor` and use `Prelude.Functor` otherwise), so my `mapped` no longer works.

So I would like to make a version of `mapped` that can work with `Functor`.  As a refresher for all who need it, the kind signature of `Functor` looks like:

```
class (Category s, Category t) => Functor (s :: α -> α -> *) (t :: β -> β -> *) (f :: α -> β) where
  map :: s a b -> t (f a) (f b)
```

This takes two of the `(->)`s in the vanilla `fmap` and replaces them with `s` and `t` which satisfy `Category`.

So if we would like to make a replacement for `mapped` we need to replace the appropriate `(->)` with generic `Category` satisfying types.  So we dealias the `Setter`:

```
mapped ::
  Prelude.Functor f =>
    ( forall g. Settable g =>
      (a -> g b) -> (f a) -> g (f b)
    )
```

In order to move forward we are going to look at `over` since we would want it to be that:

```
over mapped = map
```

Now we look at the implementation of `over` (unpacking `ASetter`):

```
over :: ((a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t) -> (a -> b) -> s -> t
over l f = runIdentity #. l (Identity #. f)
```

We can get a little bit of information out of this.  We know the types of `runIdentity`, `(#.)` and the goal.  If we work backwards

```
(#.) runIdentity (mapped (Identity #. f)) ::
  Category t => t (f a) (f b)
mapped (Identity #. f) ::
  ( Category t
  , Profunctor t
  , Coercible (f b) z
  )
    => t (f a) z
```

Which is good evidence that the third `(->)` should be replaced with a generic category, and decent evidence that the second should not.

```
mapped ::
  ( Functor s t f
  , Category s
  , Category t
  ) =>
    ( forall g. Settable g =>
      (s a (g b)) -> t (f a) (g (f b))
    )
```

And here I am stuck.  I feel as if I am pressing up against my conceptual backing here. I don't know if this type is correct or if I am missing something. Even if I did know the type I'm not sure how I would even implement `mapped` or `over`. I am used to using the prebuilt combinators out of the lens package to build my lenses and I don't think those are going to help me once I am no longer using a `Setter`.

How can I get from where I am to a working `mapped` implementation for `Functor`?

Comment: I think the problem is that the `Settable` class has the assumption of `Prelude.Applicative` (and thus `Prelude.Functor`) baked in. — Good question at any rate, I've wondered myself a lot how to best generalise lenses beyond the **Hask** category.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the type is definitely correct. Poking around in the code, `mapped` is defined as

```hs
mapped = taintedDot . fmap . untaintedDot
```

where `taintedDot`, `untaintedDot` are methods of `Settable`. As @leftaroundabout's comment makes the point, this is probably the difficulty of the translation - you would need an equivalent class for categories, though exactly what it would mean is beyond me.

A naive guess would be

```hs
class Settable f where
  untainted :: Category c => c (f a) a
  tainted   :: Category c => c a (f a)
```

which look a lot like `Monad` and `Comonad` operations, so maybe

```hs
class (forall c. Monad c f, forall c. Comonad c f) => Settable f where
  untainted :: Category c => c (f a) a
  untainted = counit
  tainted   :: Category c => c a (f a)
  tainted   = unit
```

### Alternatives...

That said, you could **cheat** - the `Profunctor` equivalent in `Category` is just an `Arrow`, since you can lift Hask arrows to categorical ones. If your `Category`s are also `Arrow`s, then you could do

```hs
data Cheat c a b = Cheat { unCheat :: c a b }

instance (Arrow c) => Profunctor (Cheat c) where
  lmap f = (arr f >>>)
  rmap f = (>>> arr f)
```

Then sneak in the `Cheat`

```hs
mapped' ::
  ( Functor s t f
  , Arrow s
  , Arrow t
  ) =>
    ( forall g. Settable g =>
      (s a (g b)) -> t (f a) (g (f b))
    )
mapped' = unCheat . taintedDot . Cheat . map . unCheat . untaintedDot . Cheat
```

Comment: “a `Profunctor` is just a `Category` which is also an `Arrow`” – um, you've got this the wrong way around. `Category` is actually a superclass of `Arrow`! Meanwhile, profunctors are _not_ categories, because they lack both identity and composition. It's closer to being true that `Arrow` is just a `Category` which is also a `Profunctor`. (From that, it follows trivially that any `Arrow` is also a `Profunctor`, which is what you used in your generic instance.)

Comment: Ah, indeed! I wasn't aware of the exact relation between `Arrow` and `Category`, so I managed to mix it all up. I'll update the answer.